# Modifying an Array

Tags: ruby

I have an Array like this

```
example_array = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']
```

And I am trying to append the timestamp to each element of the array and the output should look like

```
example_array = [{'dog': 'time_stamp'},{'cat':'time_stamp'},{'snake':'time_stamp'}]
```

I've tried this but the output is incorrect:

```
a = {}
example_array.each_with_index do |element, i|
  a.merge!("#{element}": "#{Time.now}")
  example_array.delete_at(i)
end
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution in ruby? 
I have tried a lot of ways but couldn't obtain the output like above.

Comment: Give us your Attempts

Comment: Adithya, What you're looking for is probably http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h so you can convert arrays to hashes once you group your arrays [['dog', 'time_stamp'],['cat','time_stamp]]

Comment: @iceveda06 But it should be a group of hashed inside an array.

Comment: @iceveda06. I tried that way. I get the following.
`['dog:time_stamp', 'cat:time_stamp', 'snake:time_stamp']`

Comment: Why have you chosen that data structure? I only ask because it appears (on the face of it) to be far better suited to a hash with the animals as keys. And, where does the timestamp come from?

Comment: `{ 'dog': <timestamp> }` is the same as `{ :dog=><timestamp> }`. Is that what you want, or do you want `{ 'dog'=><timestamp> }`? When you use the colon form, the key is always a symbol. The quotes around the key are only needed when the name of the key contains a whitespace character (e.g., `{ 'how are you': 'ok' }` is the same as `{ :'how are you'=>'ok' }`.

Comment: You have selected an answer that returns an array of hashes whose keys are strings even though you specified those keys to be symbols! Not good.

Comment: "the output is incorrect" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? What is the "correct" output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only weird thing is that you have to use => instead of :

```
arr = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']
arr2 = []

for index in 0 ... arr.size
  arr2.push({arr[index] => Time.now})
end

puts arr2
```

Comment: We are not in the world of C language! We are in the world of Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

Aditha,

How about this?

```
array = ["cat", "hat", "bat", "mat"]
hash = []
hash.push(Hash[array.collect { |item| [item, Time.now] } ])
```

OUTPUT:  => [{"cat"=>"2018-02-28 04:23:08 UTC", "hat"=>"2018-02-28 04:23:08 UTC", "bat"=>"2018-02-28 04:23:08 UTC", "mat"=>"2018-02-28 04:23:08 UTC"}]

Instead of item.upcase you would insert your timestamp info.  It gives me hashes inside of array.

Answer (score 1):

```
example_array.product([Time.now]).map { |k,v| { k.to_sym=>v }}
  #=> [{:dog=>2018-02-27 20:42:56 -0800},
  #    {:cat=>2018-02-27 20:42:56 -0800},
  #    {:snake=>2018-02-27 20:42:56 -0800}
```

]Note this ensures that all values (timestamps) are equal.

Comment: What's the need of requiring `time`?

Comment: `example_array.product([Time.now]).to_h`?

Comment: Anyway, upvoted for `product` which is way better than all `map`s in other responses.

Comment: @RAJ, because there's no Rails' tag. Pure Ruby requires it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No there is no need! It works fine without requiring the `time`

Comment: @mudasobwa, I had that originally but then noticed the keys were to be converted to symbols.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I was fooled by implicit key conversion.

Comment: @mudasobwa And also hash has to be inside the array but your solution simply returns a hash with many values, but expected result must be array of hashes!

Comment: @mudasobwa I have written an answer and then deleted because it returns the result of yours, `example_array.each_with_object({}){|value,h| h[value.to_sym]=Time.now}`

Comment: @RAJ, yes, you are correct about `require 'time'` not being needed. I'm in the habit of requiring it to be able to use more than the basic `Time` methods (`Time#strptime` being an example) and also `Date` and `DateTime` methods without `require 'date'`, but I should not have required it here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Okay, it's correct that we need to require date but we don't have to for Time.now.

Answer (score 0):

```
['dog', 'cat', 'snake'].map{|e| [{e.to_sym => "time_stamp"}]}
# => [[{:dog=>"time_stamp"}], [{:cat=>"time_stamp"}], [{:snake=>"time_stamp"}]]
```

Comment: Please add some description around your answer, rather than just dumping code.  Somebody with your reputation should know this!